# Excel VBA Chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-charts

I am required to create many charts on excel because I have many sets of numbers. Ideally, I would like to create a scatter plot and I am new in learning how to use excel and VBA.

I would like to create a template module code to generate a scatter plot where I can choose X and Y values for columns or rows that are not next to each other. Furthermore, I would like to be able to format the plot's details - font, size, etc.

Could someone help me create a simple template? Thank you.

I have tried doing this. I essentially want to be able to use this Macro multiple times to be able to generate many scatter plots with the same formatting, but selecting different X and Y values every single time.

What can I add to this code so that when I run it it prompts me to select desired X and Y values?

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+W
'   Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLines).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Better tell your approach for the problem first.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Show your efforts.

Comment: Start with recording a macro then possibly look at the  type argument for inputbox that allows for user selecting a range.

Comment: I have just updated the question with the code I had for a Macro I was using before. This worked when selecting a specific range, but I now want to be able to prompt the selection of X and Y values so that I can use this Macro multiple times to generate many charts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit rough and ready but shows some ideas. Apologies if any typos whilst entering via this device and you definitely want to implement better error handling.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data") 'change as appropriate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    BuildChart ws, SelectRanges(ws)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Function SelectRanges(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range

     Dim rngX As Range
     Dim rngY As Range

     ws.Activate

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     On Error Resume Next

     Set rngX = Application.InputBox("Please select X values. One column.", Type:=8)

     If rngX Is Nothing Then GoTo InvalidSelection

     Set rngY = Application.InputBox("Please select Y values. One column.", Type:=8)

     If rngY Is Nothing Then GoTo InvalidSelection

     If rngX.Columns.Count > 1 Or rngY.Columns.Count > 1 Then GoTo InvalidSelection

     On Error GoTo 0

     Set SelectRanges = Union(rngX, rngY)
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     Exit Function

InvalidSelection:
    If rngX Is Nothing Or rngY Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please ensure you have selected both X and Y ranges."
    ElseIf rngX.Rows.Count <> rngX.Rows.Count Then
         MsgBox "Please ensure the same number of rows are selected for X and Y ranges"
    ElseIf rngX.Columns.Count > 1 Or rngY.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please ensure X range has only one column and Y range has only one column"
    Else
       MsgBox "Unspecified"
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End

End Function

Private Sub BuildChart(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef unionRng As Range)

     With ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=unionRng
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks QHarr, when I tried entering this into a new module and running it, I get an error that says: Compile error: Variable not defined on line 19 - Private Function SelectRanges(Byref ws As Worksheet) As Range. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: couple of typos. Corrected. Please try now.

Comment: QHarr, thank you very much! This works greatly. 

I had one final question. In order to make everything easier and make the procedure faster, I wanted to format the charts to have a certain style. The way I see it is there are two ways of doing this:

1. I could code the formatting into the Macro

2. I could assign a template into the Macro. 

Do you know how to assign a template for the chart into a Macro?

Thank you again!

Comment: I have never tried this but if you create a template and then record a macro assigning this template style you might be find a style is applied that you later reference. Otherwise, it is easy enough to code formatting. Give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr, this has been really helpful!

Comment: So I assigned a template, and got these two lines of code:

   ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\maaro\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1.crtx")


Where would I have to add these and what would I have to change?

I am presuming that I should be adding it to the BuildChart function but I got an error. What else would I have to change?

Comment: It should go in the BuildChart function above the .SetSourceData and syntax is .ApplyChartTemplate ("C:\Users\.......crtx" ).  Don't forget to have "." at the start. Also, this will work for you but other users may not have access to the filepath.

Comment: If the desired Y values are to the left of the desired X values, Union(x, y) joins the ranges well enough, but SetSourceData applies them left to right to X and Y. You should define the X and Y ranges separately, pass them separately into the BuildChart routine, then skip SetSourceData, but use `.Values = rngY` and `.XValues = rngX`.